# TSingleHelper.AsString and packed records

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Using Delphi 10.4 and a FMX program.

I have a packed record with a "Single" type defined:

```
rRec = packed record
  ...
  Inch: Single;
  ...
end;
```

Later in the logic, I wish to display the valve of Inch as a string. There are three ways to do this:

```
var
  s: Single;
  vStr: string;
  vRec: rRec;
begin
  vRec.Inch = 12.3;

  //use FloatToStrF
  vStr := FloatToStrF(vRec.Inch, ffFixed, 7, 1);
  ...
  //Assign record value to variable and use TSingleHelper.ToString which simply calls FloatToStrF
  s := vRec.Inch;
  vStr := s.ToString(ffFixed, 7, 1);  
  ...
  //use TSingleHelper.ToString from the record value
  //***** this fails on Android *****
  vStr := vRec.Inch.ToString(ffFixed, 7, 1);
  ... 
end;
```

All three of the above examples work on Win10, OSX and IOS. However, the last one (vRec.Inch.ToString) fails on Android with the IDE showing the error "Project xx raised exception class error (10)" before showing an access violation. The "Bus" error appears in the IDE when I try to step into the ...Inch.ToString call.

Is there a known reason TSingleHelper.ToString fails on Android when used with packed record fields? Note: I have not tested this with unpacked records, or tested the helper functions for other numeric types, or tested the TSingleHelper.ToString class function.

Edit:

turns out apparently Android does not support packed records very good or at all. I noticed in my code I had three "byte" fields before the "Single" field. By adding or removing a byte field, the vRec.Inch.ToString works. Guess I will have to use FloatToStrF.

Comment: Honestly, class/record helpers are so buggy, they are rarely worth using, Quality Portal has TONS of tickets about bad helper behavior. Even the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)) says: "*Class and record helpers provide a way to extend a type, but **they should not be viewed as a design tool to be used when developing new code**. For new code you should always rely on normal class inheritance and interface implementations.*" Since `TSingleHelper.ToString()` simply calls `FloatToStrF()` anyway, no reason not to call it directly

Comment: I filed bug report https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-32457

Comment: Why are you packing records? Isn't it better to use aligned records?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan One reason for packing records would to reduce memory consumption of your application. While memory isn't really an issue on modern PC's due the fact that you have several GB of memory available and that modern PC OS'es pretty much all extend hardware memory with the use of page swapping files. On mobile platforms you don't have such luxury. Heck most mobile platforms have less total data storage capacity than average PC RAM capacity

Comment: @DavidHeffernan one thing would be for storage purposes. Saving and loading packed record that contains a lot of data is trivial code and will run extremely fast. Sometimes that speed is more important than access speed.

Comment: @Silver I don't believe that will make significant difference in real world scenarios.

Comment: @dalija Really? Again I am struggling to believe that there could be discernible gains from that scenario very often.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Take a look at FAT boot record. The only way to efficiently read that 512 bytes long thingy is to define packed record and read it all at once. This is just an example...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Really? The only way? You could use a buffered stream, and it's easy enough then to pull it out item by item. There's no real indication that this record has to be packed.

Comment: It has to be packed if it resembles the structure of a binary file with the exact same structure as the record. Yes, that can be circumvented by using streams but that would be cumbersome imho.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How significant difference it is depends on your record structure and the shear number of record objects you have. In one of my projects )game) I had about 1 M of complex records representing in-game units. When using standard records this consumed about 800 MB od memory. By using packed records it reduced memory consumption to about 500 MB. So quite a big difference. ...

Comment: ... But in the end I actually abandoned the use of records in favor of classes. You might now be confused of that because of the fact that classes store their data like regular records, plus they also bring some of their own overhead. That is true. But classes allowed me to split data for each individual into two classes. One is used for dynamically changing data. And another is used for storing static more common data that is shared by multiple units. So in the end I managed to reduce the memory consumption to about 200 MB by using classes to implement data re-usability.

Comment: @Silver Did you consider reordering the members of the record to reduce alignment gaps?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To be honest no. Would that even help? Anyway as you can see from my other post I now have an alternative solution that allowed me to get much better optimization regarding the memory usage. Not to mention that it allowed me to implement some other clever features that would not be possible by using records. Well maybe these cleaver features might be doable with the use of advanced records but at the time I must admit that I was still unaware of them.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yeah, if you go double then int, then double then int, you waste 8 bytes out of 24. But if you go double double int int then you have no waste.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I never said the only way. If you are reading one field at the time, and you have many fields then you need to write all that reading and writing code + record declaration, With packed record you only need record declaration for laying out fields and reading and writing code is literally one line. Don't get me wrong, I am not saying that records should always be packed, I am just pointing out that there are use cases where packed is the most optimal solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the reason for the packed records is because that is the way the data is being read in from external sources and dropped straight into the records. If using unpacked records then additional code is needed that requires the use of streams and field to field transfers. When talking a couple hundred different types of records, that is not trivial. However, if I find more bugs like this one, I might have to go that way, but so far it appears to only be string conversions that are causing problems on android only

Comment: @dalija your comment literally said "the only way"!! ;-)

Comment: @rick that makes sense. My approach with string / text conversion is to use my own code because of the bugs in the delphi rtl!!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan lol... emphasis on **efficiently** not taking speed as the only measure, though reading whole buffer at once is always tad faster than reading field by field, buffered stream or not...